# React <img /> tag not showing image

Tags: reactjs, image, url

I'm at a loss here, this seems so basic and easy.

Here's my code.

```
<div>
    <img src='../img/css.png' alt='CSS' />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share how your folder structure looks like in the public one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'path/to/image';

const YourComponent = () => {
  return <img src={Image} />; 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import images from public folder using following format:

```
<img
                                    alt="Duration"
                                    className={classes.hourseGlassIcon}
                                    src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/icons/duration.png'}
                                />
```

Path of my image is: root-folder-->public-->assets-->icons/duration.png.